# Angular, how to track Map <string, any>() modification?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 9 and i would like to track when my Map<string, any>() is modified.

**Context :**

I want to display in a vertical scrolling list the values of my Map using the [angular cdk scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api).

So, cause of cdkVirtualFor [data type limitation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#specifying-data), i need to create a simple array in order to display my Map data.

So i created it with Array.from(myMap.values());

```
let myMap = new Map<string, any>(); // My main Map
let myArrayToMyScrollingList = Array.from(myMap.values()); // My array to display feed by My main Map values
```

So in my HTML Component file, i have :

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="itemSize" [minBufferPx]="itemLength" [maxBufferPx]="itemLength">
     <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of myArrayToMyScrollingList">
          {{ item  }}
     </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

So it's works.

However when myMap is updated, myArrayToMyScrollingList don't apply the changement.

How to detect a Map<string, any>() value modification in order to tell my myArrayToMyScrollingList he has to update his value ?

**What i've test:**

- changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush or ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default with @Input() by passing myMap as parameter. But no change detection is found when myMap has a value modification.

Thanks for help,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes use something like this (generic way):

TS

```
private myMap = new Map<number, YourTypeHere>();
private myValues$$ = new ReplaySubject<YourTypeHere[]>(1);
public myValues$ = this.myValues$$.asObservable()


public updateMap(key,value) {
   this.myMap.set(key, value);
   this.updateMyValues();
}

private updateMyValues() {
   this.myValues.next(Array.from(this.myMap.values()));
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myValues$ async">
   {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for ur answer, i thinking about this logic in my mind. Do you think it's the best solution ?

Comment: For what you asked, yes. I angular will take care of change detection and subscription cleaning for you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be

```
get myArrayToMyScrollingList() {
  return Array.from(myMap.values());
}
```

in the component class.

Comment: Thank for ur answer,
however performance will be sad with it ? Each tick a convertion is applied ?

Comment: @polorio That is true. You can use a template pipe, like `keyvalue` (so that it will execute only when your thing changes) (but I'm not sure if it's available on Angular 9, but you can make your own).

Comment: I'm also not sure whether `keyvalue` is pure or impure. If you use a pipe of your own, and you're not going to mutate the object (but only recreate it), make your pipe pure.